# Rails delayed_job doesn't work because of ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: cannot rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active: rollback transaction

I have tried to save a large amount of data in heroku but I couldn't do that because of the response time limit of 30 seconds so I decided to use delayed_job.
However, since I have never used delayed_job so I don't know how to solve the following error

### Error

NoMethodError (undefined method `quizlet_save' for Word(id: integer, group_id: integer, user_id: integer, answer: string, question: string, title: string, image: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, answer_language: string, question_language: string, favorites_count: integer, quizlet_id: integer, check_id: string)):

## code

```
   def index
@words = params[:tag].present?? Word.tagged_with(params[:tag]) : Word.all
@words =@words.all.includes(:tags)
@groups=Group.all
@search=@words.ransack(params[:q])
@search_result = @search.result #この行を修正
@search_result = @search_result.uniq
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @search_result}
end
quizlet
```

end

```
  def quizlet
      @response=[]
               response = Unirest.get "https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/search/sets/?client_id=7JH38T27zM&whitespace=1",
                       parameters:{ whitespace: true,q: "Duo3.0",term:100,sort:"most_studied"}
      res=response.body

      quizlet_ids=[]
        res["sets"].each do|res|
           quizlet_ids<<res["id"]
       end


      quizlet_words = Unirest.get "https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/sets/?client_id=7JH38T27zM&whitespace=1",
                            parameters:{ whitespace: true,set_ids:"#{quizlet_ids}"}

   quizlet_words.body.each do|words|
     words["terms"].each do|word|
      response=word
    response["quizlet_id"]=words["id"]
    response["check_id"]=word["id"]
    response["question_language"]= words["lang_terms"]
    response["answer_language"]  = words["lang_definitions"]
    @response<<response
    @response.each do|response|
      response
      Word.delay.quizlet_save(response["quizlet_id"],response["check_id"],response["term"],response["definition"],response["question_language"],response["answer_language"])
    end
  end
end
```

end

### model

```
def quizlet_save(quizlet_id,check_id,question,answer,question_language,answer_language)
     unless Word.find_by(check_id:check_id)&&Word.find_by(quizlet_id:quizlet_id)
     Word.create(quizlet_id:quizlet_id,check_id:check_id,title:"Quizlet",question:question,answer:answer,user_id:1,tag_list:"English,duo3.0,Vocabulary",
              question_language:question_language,answer_language:answer_language)
    end
 end

  def quizlet_create_groups(quizlet_id,check_id)
   word=Word.find_by(check_id:check_id)
   unless word == nil
    checking_word=Word.find_by(quizlet_id:quizlet_id)
    group=Group.find_by(id: checking_word.group_id)
    if group==nil
       created_group=Group.new(user_id:1,title:"Quizlet",explanation:"Quizlet Duo3.0")
       created_group=created_group.save(validate: false)&&created_group
       word.update_attribute(:group_id,created_group.id)
     else
    word.update_attribute(:group_id,group.id)
    end
   end
 end
```

### environment

- ruby 2.3.1
- ruby on rails 4.2.7
- delayed_job_active_record (4.1.2)

Comment: `quizlet_save` can be called only for model objects and `response` is not a model object.

Comment: It needs too much time to save many datas so I should save  nil object first, then update?

Comment: What is the model name?

Comment: That is Word model.

Comment: Then try       `Word.new.delay.quizlet_save(response["quizlet_id"],response["check_id"],response["term"],response["definition"],response["question_language"],response["answer_language"])`

Comment: Oops possibly,saving many nil object also needs too much time?

Comment: You are not saving any nil values. You are just creating an instance of the model. Otherwise make `quizlet_save` as a model method by defining it as `def self.quizlet_save` and then call `Word.delay.quizlet_save(response["quizlet_id"],response[‌​"check_id"],response‌​["term"],response["d‌​efinition"],response‌​["question_language"‌​],response["answer_l‌​anguage"])`

Comment: Sorry,I didn't reload my browser so I couldn't check your answer.

Comment: I'm gonna try Word.new.delay.quizlet_save(response["quizlet_id"],response[‌​"check_id"],response‌​["term"],response["d‌​efinition"],response‌​["question_language"‌​],response["answer_l‌​anguage"])

Comment: I tried it but an error happened that is SyntaxError on controller.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Word.delay.quizlet_save(response["quizlet_id"],response[‌​"check_id"],response‌​["term"],response["d‌​efinition"],response‌​["question_language"‌​],response["answer_l‌​anguage"])

Comment: Please include errors in the question itself, not as an image (or a link to an image).  Among the many reasons is that the text in an image isn't indexed by search engines.

Comment: Error has changed after I fixed my syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the solution at delayed_job's Github issue.The person who is owner of delayed_job's repository  said me that you can't use any Asynchronous gems except sucker_punch in SQLite.Thank you for answering.